# Group by one column and sum by another

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, performance, rails-activerecord

Trying to write rake task that contains a query that will group by one value on a join table and then sum another column. I'd like to do it using the query interface. Purpose of this task is to find the videos that have been the most popular over the last 5 days.

In pertinent part:

```
 course_ids = Course.where(school_id: priority_schools).pluck(:id)

 sections = Section.where(course_id: course_ids)

 sections.each do |section|
   users = section.users.select {|user| user.time_watched > 0}
   user_ids = []
   users.each { |user| user_ids << user.id }

   user_videos = UserVideo.group(:video_id).
    select(:id, :video_id, :time_watched).
    where("created_at > ?", Date.today - 5.days).
    where(user_id: user_ids).sum(:time_watched)

   p "user_videos: #{user_videos.inspect}"

 end
```

Any suggestions for the how / the best way to write this query?

Comment: what's happening now when you run just the query in a console?

Comment: It seems to be returning key value pairs of video_id: sum_time_watched. I think I need to next find the largest time watched per section.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the actual `SELECTs` you are asking about.  RoR can be obfuscative.